# Azure websites 404 index.html

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, .net-core

I'm trying to run my application on an Azure Website,
but I'm having problems getting my `index.html` to work.

The application exists out of 2 projects:

- Api (.net core)
- Client (angular)

In my build definition I copy the results from my Client and Api to the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`
And then I publish that

So far so good, I can see the files from my client listed in the `wwwroot` of my website (via the kudu console)

but when I navigate to the `index.html` it I get a **404**. However going to the `/api/...` link is just working like intended

So I'm thinking the problem is my `web.config` overwriting the posibility to navigate to the index.html file.

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Portal4Fun.Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In .net core, are you using the static files middleware?  https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html  if you miss this out, no static content will be served.

Comment: @RussellYoung: that was it, combined with copying it to the wwwroot/wwwroot/ folder :) will you reply with it so I can accept it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .net Core you need to make sure you're using the static files middleware, please see [static files documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html) to see how to add this - it should be there by default on a new .net Core Project.  Without this middleware, no static files will be served - eg. *.css, *.js, *.html, etc!